# Cursor change on mouseclick

Tags: xna

I have a simple custom cursor code that loads a cursor from my Content folder to a Texutre2D, and then simply draws it on Draw. How can I program the image to change when I hold right click and then switch back to default when I release right click?

Comment: If someone answered the last question you asked, you really should mark their answer as so. Others will probably be more willing to help you if they see you mark answers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to load both your textures in two `Texture2D` variables, then simply check in your `Update` the state of the right button.

```cs
if (mouse.RightButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
   cursorTexture = pressedTexture;
else
   cursorTexture = releasedTexture;
```

Of course, `cursorTexture` is the one you have to draw.